# How to plot a single data point with Google charts API column chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

When I try to create a column chart using the Google charts visualization javascript API the bar ends up a lot fatter than I expected.

Here's a comparison of two charts that demonstrates the problem.  First, a chart with two data points where the resulting bars look normal, then a chart with a single data point where the resulting bar looks weird.

The only difference between the two snippets is:

```
// two bars
data.addRows([
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1],
]);
```

vs.

```
// one bar
data.addRows([
    [1, 1]
]);
```

### Two bars (looks normal)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisTickColors);

function drawAxisTickColors() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');

  // two bars
  data.addRows([
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Tidy lil bars',
    hAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 4
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

### Single bar (looks weird)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisTickColors);

function drawAxisTickColors() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');

  // one bar
  data.addRows([
    [1, 1],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Big ol bar',
    hAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 4
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bar.groupWidth` to control the width of the columns

from the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options)...

> The width of a group of bars, specified in either of these formats:
>
> - Pixels (e.g. 50).
> - Percentage of the available width for each group (e.g. '20%'), where '100%' means that groups have no space between them.
>
> *Type*: number or string
>   *Default*: The golden ratio, approximately '61.8%'.

i.e. --> `bar: { groupWidth: 100 },  //100px`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawAxisTickColors,
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
});

function drawAxisTickColors() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');

  data.addRows([
    [1, 1],
    //[2, 1],
  ]);

  var options = {
    bar: { groupWidth: 100 },  //100px
    title: 'Tidy lil bars',
    hAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 4
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```